# How do you write articles without plagiarizing when everything has essentially been said about the topic at hand?

Tags: non-fiction

Basically, when dealing with non-fiction topics like business or security or Information Technology or any other factual topic, there is really only so many ways you can write the facts using the English language. For example in business, when writing about forming a company you have a certain "checklist" you go through when forming a company, things you have to do. Things to take in to consideration etc. There is really only a few ways to describe it. Then when 400 other people wrote 2000 other articles about that subject, you can't write it without technically write the same way as someone else. And no, the answer is not "then don't write it", because when you have let's say a business blog, you really have to have that base of articles so that your readers can get through the entire process that you are trying to describe on your site and not have to jump to other sites to fill in the blanks.

So, again, taking that into consideration, how do you write articles without plagiarizing when everything has essentially been said about the topic at hand?

Comment: Of course, when truly everything has already been said about a topic, one question to ask yourself is whether the world needs yet another article about it, or whether the time would be better spent on another topic.

Comment: Read. Respond. Engage. Mature articles are able to engage with sources and explain why they're valuable or why they should be set aside, ideally to scaffold a claim that is original to you, your experience, and your audience.

Answer (score 6):

Write about the articles themselves. Do research and summarize them; they can't all be identical. Then you can say, with credit,

> John Smith puts this point best, in his article "What to Do and What to Not: Forming an LLC": [advice].

In other words, embrace the fact that there are so many articles, and use them. For every point you want to make, some one of those dozens or hundreds of authors said it best, or most clearly, or most succinctly. So use it. Tie them together. Don't use the same author twice, you don't want your reader to say "I should just read that guy".

Instead, you produce an article that seems to bring it all together, like in music the best hits in Country Music, 1970-1979, or whatever. You are adding value by showing them in ONE article what they would have to read twenty articles to see.

Comment: Yes, many self-help articles avoid this even when OBVIOUSLY the author did not come up with all these ideas in a void. You can stand out by making yourself a _better_ one-stop shopping destination. I think it's important that you aren't just borrowing content, however-- you should also provide some amount of analysis, criticism, or other commentary to this work. "John Smith says, "license your LLC in Delaware". Here's why I think this is a good/bad idea. Cons: local taxes support your state and community."